# Display DataTable data in Seperate GridViews C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an aspx page with GridViews. I am using the gridview to act like a questionnaire. In a GridView, there are 4 Columns(Name, Company, Question, Answer) and 5 rows with textbox. There is a TextBox on the header where you type your name, So there are a total of 6 TextBox. After saving, the table looks like this:

```
name1 | company1 | question1 | answer1
name1 | company1 | question2 | answer2
name1 | company1 | question3 | answer3
name1 | company1 | question4 | answer4
name1 | company1 | question5 | answer5

name2 | company1 | question1 | answer1
name2 | company1 | question2 | answer2
name2 | company1 | question3 | answer3
name2 | company1 | question4 | answer4
name2 | company1 | question5 | answer5
```

and so on. Now my problem is, I don't know how to display them on separate gridviews after saving in Database. Say I want to display all records from company1, `name1`'s records should be displayed in a gridview and `name2`'s records should be displayed in a separate gridview. I need this for my Search Function. How can I do this?

Comment: Please use diferent DataView Object to filter your Datatable as per different conditions(companies) and then you can bind them to different GridViews.

Comment: You can use separate Data Tables for each GridView each one filtering the SQL by the condition of your choice.

Comment: @GaganDeep Thank you for your idea, can you somehow write a sample code? Or some links where I can see some samples? I haven't tried that before, so I am searching about DataView right now.

Comment: @AsafEpelbaum uhm, that is actually my problem. I don't know how can I use separate DataTables on my situation.

Comment: @PauGacusan I suggested to create several separated SQL statements each one getting another chunk of data by your needs. What GangaDeep suggested is that you get all the data from the database at once, then filter the GridViews according to your needs. It is the same result with different implementations, each one has advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this..

```
DataView dv = datatablename.DefaultView;
//get unique companies
DataTable distinctcompanynames = dv.ToTable(true,"companycolumnname");

foreach (DataRow dr in distinctgrouptype.Rows)
    {

        dv.RowFilter = "itemgrouptype='"+dr[0].ToString()+"'";
        //get different DataViews
        DataView singltable = dv.ToTable().DefaultView;  
        //here you can bind          
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it first. Will leave a feedback/comment later.

Comment: what is distinctgrouptype?

Comment: That is my columnname on which I want to filter the data

Comment: is distinctcompanynames different to distinctgrouptype?

Comment: Yes. Distinctcompanynames contain distinct companies. See the difference in ToTable method I used.

Comment: Okay I went and did some trial and errors. I think I can make this work now. Thank you!

Comment: great. glad it helped you.